# Android: Human click vs. Junit click

Tags: android, junit

When I click a button, which opens a new activity, the onStop() methode is called.
When Junit clicks the same button, the methode isn't called.

What's the difference? Can I force my app to execute the onStop() methode whenever a new intent is shown?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: What are you trying to test? What's the parent class of your test?

Comment: In my "Settings" Activity, settings are stored in the onStop() Methode.
A human click on the "back" button stores the settings (shared preferences) and sends a short toast, when junit clicks the button, the test is over, nothing happens.

parent class? the testclass extends ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2, if you are talking about that!?